# What does the syntax <T, U = T> mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am familiar with the syntax `<T, U>` and its purpose but I am a bit confused with the syntax `<T, U = T>` and I can't find it in the typescript documentation. Please recommend reading material. Thanks.

I have tried reading the typescript documentation but I can't seem to find any mention of `<T, U = T>`

Comment: Just a guess: it means that you can use `new Class<T>` to mean `new Class<T,T>`, i.e. if `U` is not specified, it will be the same type as `T`. Not doing much TypeScript, so a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It provides a default value for the `U` type which, in this case, it is the `T` type.

Take a look at this example:

```
// This is our good old generic type. It needs to be provided or it will be inferred if possible
function myFunc<T>() {}

// Same as before but, it will use `string` type for `T` unless it is provided
function myFunc<T = string>() {}

// Same as the first example with 2 type parameters
function myFunc<T, U>() {}

// Also 2 type parameters but the second one will be `string` if not provided
function myFunc<T, U = string>() {}

// Also 2 type parameters but the second one will be `T` if not provided
function myFunc<T, U = T>() {}
```